# how to implement o embed in java jquery web application while saving hyperlinks entered by users

Tags: java, jsp, oembed

I have a java jquery web application in which users can paste utube,vimeo urls could anyone pls tell how i can implement o-embedd to show users a thumbnail of the the image/desc of url in my jsp page

Comment: no i dunt knw wht to use

Comment: i used this code Content URL: <input type="text" id="update"/><button id="btn">Get</button> <div id="embed"></div> 
The jQuery Code

$(function(){     $('#btn').click(function() {         $("#embed").oembed($('#update').val());     }); });

Comment: but any ideas on how to save o embedd urls the json object